# preg_split in php to split string at the point which is preceded by digit and is followed by letters or blank space

Tags: php, regex, date, delimiter, preg-split

In order to split my string at the point which is preceded by digit and is followed by letters as:

```
 $str = '12jan';
```

I have used

```
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$str);
```

It works file and gives the desired output. I want to update it so that it gives the same output for strings like.

```
$str='12 jan';
$str='12    jan';
$str='12/jan';
$str='12//jan';
$str='12/jan';
$str='12*/jan';
$str='12*//jan';
```

The code should work for any strings given above so that at the end of the day I have a array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => jan
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to create a separate ` preg_split` for each desired string

Comment: ...No way @dean  (sorry, I can't downvote your comment)

Comment: @Rekha are these values part of a larger string or is this the entire input string?  Please clarify how `$str` can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be optimized if you answer my question in the comment.

Pattern: `~(?<=[0-9])[*/ ]*(?=[a-z]+)~i`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPjA1i/4)

The above will match zero or more `*`, `/` and/or space characters.

---

On your input strings, this will be just as accurate and faster:

Pattern: `~\d+\K[^a-z]*~i`
or:  `~\d+\K[*/ ]*~`  (no case-sensitive pattern modifier is necessary)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPjA1i/3)

The above will match zero or more non-alphabetical characters immediately following the leading digit(s).

---

And of course `preg_split`'s cousins can also do nicely:

**Here is [a battery of PHP Demos](https://3v4l.org/prlLp).**

```
$strings=['12jan','12 jan','12    jan','12/jan','12//jan','12/jan','12*/jan','12*//jan'];

foreach($strings as $string){
    var_export(preg_split('~(?<=[0-9])[*/ ]*(?=[a-z]+)~i',$string));
    echo "\n";
    var_export(preg_split('~\d+\K[*/ ]*~',$string));
    echo "\n";
    var_export(preg_match('~(\d+)[/* ]*([a-z]+)~i',$string,$out)?array_slice($out,1):'fail');
    echo "\n";
    var_export(preg_match('~(\d+)[/* ]*(.+)~',$string,$out)?array_slice($out,1):'fail');
    echo "\n";
    var_export(preg_match_all('~\d+|[a-z]+~i',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

All methods provide the same output.

Comment: I always endeavor (and advise others) to avoid/minimize the use of capture groups, lookarounds, alternatives, and lazy quantifiers in an effort to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code with preg_match
Its gives output what exactly your needs

```
$str='12/jan';
preg_match('/^(\d*)[\*\s\/]*([a-z]{3})$/i', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

but the output is changed a little bit, It will be like below

```
array(
  0 => '12/jan', 
  1 => '12', 
  2 => 'jan'
)
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex, offers no explanation and features unnecessary escaping.

Comment: This Maybe complex, But it gives the output as he wants

Answer (score 0):

A simple preg_match regexp does it:

```
foreach (['12 jan', '12    jan', '12/jan', '12//jan', '12/jan',
          '12*/jan', '12*//jan'] as $test)
{
        unset ($matches);
        if (preg_match("#^([0-9]+)[ /*]*(.*)#", $test, $matches)) {
                var_export( [$matches[1], $matches[2]] );
        }
        else {
                print "Failed for '$test'.\n";
        }
}
```

The regexp is:

- start with numbers -> group #1
- have 0 or more of space, slash or stars
- take all the rest -> group #2